# Issue with converting a function from ES6 to vanilla JavaScript to work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I created a Directory Search using regex to match the input to the data. I followed a tutorial for half of it and added to it on my own. It is working in Chrome, but not Internet Explorer.

I figured out this is due to ES6 incompatibilities in Internet Explorer and now I am having trouble figuring out how to correctly convert my **`displayMatches`** function to vanilla javascript or jQuery with no ES6.

So far most of it is working except that I can't figure how to remove the commas in in my html for the list of matches even though I tried using **`.join('')`**

[Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhHUu.png)

[Screenshot #2 - see the commas in between?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYUou.png)

**This is the working code on Chrome:**

```
function displayMatches() {
    // console.log(this.value);
    $('.suggestions').show();
    var matchArray = findMatches(this.value, employees);
    console.log(matchArray);
    var html = matchArray.slice(0,10).map(person => {
        var regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
        var firstName = person.GivenName.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
        var lastName = person.Surname.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
        var extension;

        if (person.Phone_Ext1 !== null){
            extension = person.Phone_Ext1;
        } else {extension = "N/A"}

        return `
            <li class="search-item" data-id=${person.EmployeeID}>
                <span class="person">${firstName} ${lastName}</span>
                <span class="phone-ext">Ext. ${extension}</span>
            </li>
        `
    }).join('');

    if ($('#search-box').val() == ""){
        suggestions.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        suggestions.innerHTML = html;
    }
}
```

**And this is my attempt to convert:**

```
function displayMatches() {
    // console.log(this.value);
    $('.suggestions').show();
    var matchArray = findMatches(this.value, employees);
    console.log(matchArray);

    var html = [];
    var person;
    var list;

    for(var i=0; i < matchArray.slice(0,10).length; i++){
        person = matchArray.slice(0,10)[i];
        var regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
        var hilight = '<span class="hl">' + this.value + '</span>';
        var firstName = person.GivenName.replace(regex, hilight);
        var lastName = person.Surname.replace(regex, hilight);
        var extension;

        if (person.Phone_Ext1 !== null){
            extension = person.Phone_Ext1;
        } else {
            extension = "N/A"
        }

        list =
            '<li class="search-item" data-id=' + person.EmployeeID +'>' +
            '<span class="person">' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + '</span>' +
            '<span class="phone-ext">Ext. ' + extension + '</span>' +
            '</li>';
        html.push(list);
    }
    html.join('');
    console.log(html);

    if ($('#search-box').val() == ""){
        suggestions.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        suggestions.innerHTML = html;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can still use `matchArray.slice(0,10).map(...` you just have to replace the arrow function inside with a regular old `function`.

Comment: @Bergi: Post as answer, please. Also, good job spotting that.

Comment: @H.B. it's done

Comment: @H.B. i did try to replace it with `function(person)` and that didn't work until i changed it to a for loop

Comment: @staysee: What version of IE do you try to target then? Must be ancient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html.join('')` *returns* a new string. It doesn't transmogrify the array to a string, it doesn't assign a new value to the `html` variable. You would need to do

```
html = html.join('');
```

or even better use two separate variables, one of the array and one for the string.

Btw, you don't even need to construct and fill the array yourself in a loop, you can use the [ES5 Array `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) since IE9. As @H.B. remarked in the comments, you only need to use a `function` expression instead of the arrow syntax.

Comment: I did try replacing with `function` like @H.B. commented but that didn't work. And wow I completely did not think about assigning the value...careless mistake. Thanks!